# extracing multiple strings between separator characters from a large string?

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a large string extracted from an individual CSV celll with data similar to this:

```
*** NOTE ***
2016-09-17
I called to check his data.  They hadn't sent BUT he also didn't have any appointments that day, so we'll wait and see.  Will call tuesday and see if they've sent that day.
*** NOTE ***
2016-09-16
John sent a message saying his data may have issue.
I checked the server logs and indeed, the data bork on the 9th. I'll keep an eye on them each day to be sure.
*** EMAIL ***
2016-09-15 printer update 
Robert Smith <robertsmith@someurl.com> to: someuser@anotherurl.com
Good morning John, this is some feedback from our recent call.
If you could please...
```

This goes on for many megabytes and I need to move through that string and extract every separate piece of data broken as so:

- Type
- Date
- Body

So in one of the above examples I'd need to extract similar to:

```
Type  : NOTE
Date : 2016-09-17
Body : I called to check his data.  They hadn't sent BUT he also didn't have any appointments that day, so we'll wait and see.  Will call tuesday and see if they've sent that day.
```

Once I have the 3 x extracted string/s I know what to do next, but right now I'm a little stumped on how to figure out this pattern and extract using it.

What technique/s could I use to parse this, find the `*** NOTE ***` or `*** EMAIL ***` as the first separator then go from there?

I'm using Flask/Python.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: do you know about regular expressions? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re.split` and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """*** NOTE ***
2016-09-17
I called to check his data.  They hadn't sent BUT he also didn't have any appointments that day, so we'll wait and see.  Will call tuesday and see if they've sent that day.
*** NOTE ***
2016-09-16
John sent a message saying his data may have issue.
I checked the server logs and indeed, the data bork on the 9th. I'll keep an eye on them each day to be sure.
*** EMAIL ***
2016-09-15 printer update 
Robert Smith <robertsmith@someurl.com> to: someuser@anotherurl.com
Good morning John, this is some feedback from our recent call.
If you could please..."""


data = re.split(r"\*\*\* ([A-Z]+) \*\*\*", s)[1:]
for type_val, cont in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2]):
    print("Type: ", type_val)
    date, body = cont.strip().split("\n", 1)
    print("Date: ", date)
    print("Body: ", body)
    print("------")
```

**Output:**

```
('Type: ', 'NOTE')
('Date: ', '2016-09-17')
('Body: ', "I called to check his data.  They hadn't sent BUT he also didn't have any appointments that day, so we'll wait and see.  Will call tuesday and see if they've sent that day.")
------
('Type: ', 'NOTE')
('Date: ', '2016-09-16')
('Body: ', "John sent a message saying his data may have issue.\nI checked the server logs and indeed, the data bork on the 9th. I'll keep an eye on them each day to be sure.")
------
('Type: ', 'EMAIL')
('Date: ', '2016-09-15 printer update ')
('Body: ', 'Robert Smith <robertsmith@someurl.com> to: someuser@anotherurl.com\nGood morning John, this is some feedback from our recent call.\nIf you could please...')
------
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions really shine at this. Here's an example on how to tackle this:

```
import re                                                                      
from collections import namedtuple                                             

TEXT = """
*** NOTE ***                                                                   
2016-09-17                                                                     
I called to check his data.  They hadn't sent BUT he also didn't have any appointments that day, so we'll wait and see.  Will call tuesday and see if they've sent that day.
*** NOTE ***                                                                   
2016-09-16                                                                     
John sent a message saying his data may have issue.                            
I checked the server logs and indeed, the data bork on the 9th. I'll keep an eye on them each day to be sure.
*** EMAIL ***                                                                  
2016-09-15 printer update                                                   
Robert Smith <robertsmith@someurl.com> to: someuser@anotherurl.com             
Good morning John, this is some feedback from our recent call.              
If you could please...                                                         
"""                                                                            

parts = re.split(re.compile(r"^\*\*\* ", re.MULTILINE), TEXT)[1:]              

expression = r"^(?P<type>.*) \*\*\*\n(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?P<body>.*)"
pattern = re.compile(expression, re.DOTALL)                                    

Message = namedtuple("Message", ("type", "date", "body"))                      

messages = []                                                                  
for part in parts:                                                             
    match = pattern.match(part)                                                
    messages.append(                                                           
        Message(match.group("type"), match.group("date"), match.group("body"))
    )
```

First, we split the string based into parts that start with '***' at the beginning of a line. Then, we loop through the parts and match it with an expression using the very powerful feature of named groups, which we then afterwards use to fetch the data and store it into a namedtuple.

You might still want to do some data cleaning, with `strip()` or more regular expressions. :-)

Hope this helps!